# Android IntentService is killed after close application

Tags: android

i have android application which send requests to server.

my application was sending requests successfully when i my application is run,

but when i close the app, my IntentService stop sending any request

my IntentService code:

```
public class ServiceNotification extends IntentService {
    public static boolean ServiceIsRun = false;
    public static int NotifiationID = MainActivity.NotificatiosFromServer;
    public String Id = MainActivity.Id;
    public String NotifiationMessage;

    public ServiceNotification() {
        super("ServiceNotification");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        while (ServiceIsRun) {
            try { // here the function send requests to server and i print this request in server console.
                GetUserNotification(new MainPage.VolleyCallBack() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        NotifiationID++;
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

BroadcastReceiver  code:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static int id = 1;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // get the bundles in the message
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        // check the action equal to the action we fire in broadcast,
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("com.example.Broadcast")) {
            id++;
            //read the data from the Intent Service
            NewNotificationMessage notfilyme = new NewNotificationMessage();
            notfilyme.notify(context, bundle.getString("msg"), bundle.getString("Image"),  bundle.getInt("Id"));
        }

    }
}
```

ActivityMain.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
if (!ServiceNotification.ServiceIsRun) {
                                ServiceNotification.ServiceIsRun = true;
                                //register the services to run in background
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceNotification.class);
                                // start the services
                                startService(intent);
                            }
}
}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/applicationicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
<receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:priority="2147483647">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> <!-- register the service -->
        <service
            android:name=".ServiceNotification"
            android:exported="false"
            android:enabled="true">
        </service>
    </application>
```

How can i keep my Intent Service work after my application closed

Answer (score 0):

First you can try:

```java
    public ServiceNotification() {
        super("ServiceNotification");
        setIntentRedelivery(true); // this will restart your service after app gets killed
    }
```

See if this works for you, I think you need to test on a real phone without power plugged. Because Android doesn't allow long time task running at background without notifying user for saving power, so it is very possible that your service will stop after some time, it will be shorter if you put off your screen.

So the alternative is to start a foreground service, like this:

```java
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        startForeground(1, getNotification());
        // do your work here
        while (ServiceIsRun) {
            // do the work and see if it completes
            // if it is completed, call: 
            // stopForegrond(true);
            // stopSelf();
            // break;
        }
   }

   // create the notification but it maybe not shown on Android 8.0+
   // because we don't create/set the notification channel
   private Notification getNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder b=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        b.setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setContentText("text")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
                .setTicker("ticker");

        return(b.build());
    }
```

Comment: Keep it as is now will be ok

Comment: thanks,but startForeground(1, getNotification()); it is good if i want to keep notification appears to user, but i want other thing
i want to keep my function work when my app is close.
startForeground accept a notification function not a void function

Comment: when i call startForeground(1, getNotification()); my function still working after app closed but the notification of  getNotification() still apears

Comment: You need to let user know you're doing something at background, so a notification is required which is asked by Android

Comment: yes i understand that, but i want to send notification like facebook and whatsapp.
send request to server and if there notification it will display and user can cancel it

Comment: You can't prevent users from stopping your app or kill your app from Phone Settings > Running apps, unless, you tell them what your app doing is they expect. For example for a net disk app, you can issue a notification to user say your app is uploading the selected files to server. I believe user will not cancel it (unless they don't want to do that right now)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:stopWithTask="false"` in your service in manifest,like this :

```
<service
      android:name=".ServiceNotification"
      android:exported="false"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:stopWithTask="false"> 
</service>
```

Adding it will make your service continue even after the app is closed/killed.

---

Also, you have another requirement of not showing a persistent **notification**, for this you can use [JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService)

For more : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Answer (score 0):

Android IntentService is designed to handle long running but short lived work in a worker thread. Unlike a service, which runs in a main thread, it is guaranteed to run in a worker thread. If you have work that you want to last long and beyond the life of your app, one way to accomplish that would be to use a regular service and create a new thread. Start the service with sticky so it will start even when the user restarts your app.

Comment: thanks, but what if i used IntentService with foreground?.... is there any problem?